# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError error when connecting to RedissonClient

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, redis, redisson

I'm working on a Java spring project in which I used Redis as my hibernate second level cache provider,through setting the factory_class to
CustomRedissonRegionFactory that extends `RedissonRegionFactory`, I overridden the method `createRedissonClient` to return a RedissonClient with this configurations

```
final Config redissonConfig = new Config();
        redissonConfig.useSingleServer()
                .setKeepAlive(true)
                .setConnectTimeout(REDIS_CONNECT_TIMEOUT)
                .setRetryAttempts(REDIS_RETRY_ATTEMPTS)
                .setDnsMonitoringInterval(REDIS_DNS_MONITORING_INTERVAL)
                .setAddress(redisAddress);
```

However when I try to run any Rest method that deals with the a RedissonClient like evicting keys by using `redissonClient.getKeys().flushallAsync();` it returns this Error

```
Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
14-Nov-2022 10:25:46.946 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(18)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/config/LocalConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1071)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1082)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:540)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:171)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1014)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4952)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5266)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1775)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:291)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:291)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(Unknown Source)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(Unknown Source)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(Unknown Source)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        ... 65 more
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:967)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
        at com.config.LocalConfiguration.generateEntityManagerFactory(LocalConfiguration.java:140)
        at com.config.LocalConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(LocalConfiguration.java:35)
        at com.config.LocalConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6bd9a4d3.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$1(<generated>)
        at com.config.LocalConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6bd9a4d3$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$857ee161.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
        at com.config.LocalConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6bd9a4d3.entityManagerFactory(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 66 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheImplementor]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.getService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:80)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:244)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889)
        ... 82 more
    Caused by: org.redisson.client.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to Redis server: 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:6379
        at org.redisson.connection.pool.ConnectionPool.lambda$createConnection$1(ConnectionPool.java:153)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source)
        at org.redisson.connection.pool.ConnectionPool.promiseFailure(ConnectionPool.java:317)
        at org.redisson.connection.pool.ConnectionPool.lambda$createConnection$7(ConnectionPool.java:276)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(Unknown Source)
        at org.redisson.client.RedisClient$1$1.run(RedisClient.java:241)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        ... 1 more
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeRelay(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeRelay(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniRelay(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniRelay.tryFire(Unknown Source)
        ... 10 more
    Caused by: io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToByteEncoder.write(MessageToByteEncoder.java:125)
        at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandEncoder.write(CommandEncoder.java:75)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:715)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:707)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:790)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:700)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToByteEncoder.write(MessageToByteEncoder.java:120)
        at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandBatchEncoder.write(CommandBatchEncoder.java:45)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:715)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:788)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:756)
        at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandsQueue.write(CommandsQueue.java:83)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:715)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:788)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:756)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:806)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1025)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:294)
        at org.redisson.client.RedisConnection.send(RedisConnection.java:206)
        at org.redisson.client.RedisConnection.async(RedisConnection.java:252)
        at org.redisson.client.RedisConnection.async(RedisConnection.java:224)
        at org.redisson.client.RedisConnection.async(RedisConnection.java:220)
        at org.redisson.client.handler.BaseConnectionHandler.channelActive(BaseConnectionHandler.java:90)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:228)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:214)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:207)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelActive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1398)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:228)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelActive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:214)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelActive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:895)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:305)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:335)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        ... 4 more
    Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateMemory(Native Method)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0.allocateDirectNoCleaner(PlatformDependent0.java:453)
        at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.allocateDirectNoCleaner(PlatformDependent.java:699)
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.allocateDirect(PoolArena.java:758)
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.newChunk(PoolArena.java:734)
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocateNormal(PoolArena.java:245)
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:215)
        at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:147)
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:356)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:187)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:178)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.ioBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:131)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToByteEncoder.allocateBuffer(MessageToByteEncoder.java:140)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToByteEncoder.write(MessageToByteEncoder.java:105)
        ... 41 more
```

Any help is apreciated!

Comment: I think the problem is related to Redis connection - Unable to connect to Redis server: 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:6379

Comment: I thought of that as it could be that redis server is running out of memory or reaching maximum clients, but I have set the maxmemory to be 100mb only 7.8mb is used, and I've set the maxclients to be 300 only 101 connections is used, do you think it could be lack of available ports maybe? or something else?